power automate with downloadable url link not working as intendent to download the file
i receive reports in email as a link which i click and download in csv format. Now with the help of power automate am able to get the downloadable url which works fine to download a csv file.

with the help of power automate is use uploadurl action to download the file in onedrive.
downloaded file doesnot have extension
i manually add .csv in filename in uploadurl action and it dowloads the csv file but it
does not have the actual csv content it doctype HTMl file content.
if i use the URL seperately am able to download the CSV.

any option in power automate will help to solve my problem?
Thanks in advance
